# Renaming all the folders centos

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, directory

can anyone tell me how to rename all the folders in a directory from terminal?
every folder is in format of "id-namestring", is there any way to rename using this pattern to remove everything after "id" in the folder name?
for example if folder name is "123-abcd&efg" it should be renamed to "123"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find top-level-dir -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/(\d+)-.+/$1/'
```

This will rename all the directories (`-type d`) contained in the directory `top-level-dir`.

`xargs` is used to cope with the case of very long list of files. `-print0` and `-0` is for the case when your file names contain spaces.

`s/(\d+)-.+/$1/` is the actual regexp used for renaming.

Comment: Hi, above command worked like a charm in my local ubuntu but when i tried the same with using ssh login to my server which is running Centos it not seems to be working is there anything i'm doing wrong in server? FYI i'm running amazon ec2 instance

Comment: Could you elaborate what does 'seems not to work' mean? What is the error that you get? Also, CentOS version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Perl expression if you feel comfortable with this.

in this link you can find an overview of rename command with [this](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/rename.htm) perl expressions